# How do you cancel a download in Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, file-transfer

I'm trying to set up a download manager for my Expo app so it can download thumbnails or content from a remote service and I'm going through the [FileSystem docomentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/).

I see the `pauseAsync` that should pause the download, but no `cancelAsync`.  Would cancel be a matter of `pauseAsync` and then `deleteAsync` ?

Comment: Hi, I’m looking to cancel a download too. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
  'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4'
);

await downloadResumable.cancelAsync();
```